# How can I sort my woocommerce products on the shop page by category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently trying to rearrange my shop page but I've hit abit of a snag, the shop page seems to have mixed the product categories into one big mess, it may be arranging by alphabetical order.

I'd like to arrange it but categories, so for example all the category one items show then blend into category two then three, ect.

I Have found that you can simply drag and drop the products and that seems to change the order as well as applying a position in the menu order tab, but this is a time consuming way and I think it'll become a problem when trying to add more products to the categories down the line.

If anyone has a suggestion or can point me in the right direction i'd be most grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never managed to find a fast way around it, Dragging and dropping still did the trick.

Comment: i agree with this statement, it seems viable